# How do you turn a series on and off in C#

Tags: c#, graph, charts, data-visualization

I am trying to build an FFT plotting program. I've got all I need for the FFT's but now I'm stuck on plotting. I want to allow the user to turn on a plot of the input data and the output data. I want them to be able to have them on the same chart or not. Currently the code I've got is

```
if(myCheckBox.Checked == true)
{
for(int i = 0 ; ...)
      {chart is filled}
}
else
{
  turn off series being displayed  
}
```

It's this else part that I am having severe trouble with and was hoping to get a couple of pointers(Ha!).

Comment: Which charting library are you using ?

Comment: The `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide a series in MSChart, use the `Enabled` property this way :

```
msChart.Series["Series"].Enabled = false;
```

and to show it again :

```
msChart.Series["Series"].Enabled = true;
```